# Trying to use Fn + F(number) keys at the same time I'd like to use standard function keys - did this before and can't do it again

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I use F5 and F3 frequently for playing Minecraft. I enable using "F1, F2, etc as standard function keys" for these to work in the client (*I use fn+f5 or fn+f3 and not just the function key to clear it up*), but when I enable this, I can't use my volume keys or any of my standard function keys properly. I would like to be able to use these at the same time but I have to toggle the settings every time which is inconvenient.

I didn't have this problem before at all - I could use them at the same time, and I changed some keybind settings trying to resolve a different issue today (with F3 and F5 as well), which may be the problem, but I think I reset those settings. I would like to figure out how to re-enable these features if it's possible.